# Forecasting Sales LSTM - cannot capture peak values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, forecasting, predictive-models, lstm

I am trying to forecast retail sales for a company that have different stores.

I currently use LSTM model which is designed as follows: data includes the info about sales between 2014-2020.

After splitting train test data for all stores, I concatenated them and train the model with combined values.

For now, I have the same architecture but different model weights for all items and that means each items' time series are being combined for training and prediction is made on items' specific model weights.

Anyway, even though my network architecture captures the pattern very well, it gets stuck on peak values and cannot give good results for the peak values. Here are some forecast results, that would be great to hear some advices. All pictures are same item but different stores,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`lstm_itemStgt`, `lstm_itemKoln`, and `lstm_itemMN` refer to different stores, and they are time series data which are multivariate with features: discount, unit price, day of week, season (summer, winter, etc.):

> > [image]

```py
def trainModel(X_train,n_batch=64):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences = True,activation='relu',
                   input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(units =64,activation='relu',return_sequences = True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.7))
    #model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units =50,activation='relu',return_sequences = True)))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    #model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
    #model.add(Dense(10,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(10,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))
    lr_schedule = optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=1e-3,
        decay_steps=50,
        decay_rate=0.9)
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)  
    return model

df_history = pd.DataFrame()

df_future = pd.DataFrame()             
temp_dictKoln = pd.DataFrame()
temp_dictStgt = pd.DataFrame()
temp_dictMnhm = pd.DataFrame()
temp_accKoln = pd.DataFrame()
temp_accStgt = pd.DataFrame()
temp_accMnhm = pd.DataFrame()                                                                                   
for index in range(1):
    item_woDummyStgt = grouped_dfStgt.get_group(items[index]).iloc[:,1:]
    item_woDummyKoln = grouped_dfKoln.get_group(items[index]).iloc[:,1:]
    item_woDummyMN = grouped_dfMN.get_group(items[index]).iloc[:,1:]
    lstm_itemStgt = getDFDummies(item_woDummyStgt,drop_first=True)
    lstm_itemKoln =  getDFDummies(item_woDummyKoln,drop_first=True)
    lstm_itemMN =  getDFDummies(item_woDummyMN,drop_first=True)
    train_scaledStgt, test_scaledStgt,item_stdevStgt = scaled_split(lstm_itemStgt)
    train_scaledKoln, test_scaledKoln,item_stdevKoln = scaled_split(lstm_itemKoln)
    train_scaledMN, test_scaledMN,item_stdevMN = scaled_split(lstm_itemMN)
    X_trainStgt, y_trainStgt,X_testStgt,y_testStgt= train_testSplit(train_scaledStgt,test_scaledStgt,120)
    X_trainKoln, y_trainKoln,X_testKoln,y_testKoln= train_testSplit(train_scaledKoln,test_scaledKoln,120)
    X_trainMN, y_trainMN,X_testMN,y_testMN = train_testSplit(train_scaledMN,test_scaledMN,120)
    training_array = np.concatenate((X_trainStgt,X_trainKoln,X_trainMN,X_trainMN))
    output_array = np.concatenate((y_trainStgt,y_trainKoln,y_trainMN,y_trainMN))
    training_val_array = np.concatenate((X_testStgt,X_testKoln,X_testMN,X_testMN))
    output_val_array = np.concatenate((y_testStgt,y_testKoln,y_testMN,y_testMN))

    item_stdevStgt = item_stdevStgt[-len(X_testStgt):]
    item_stdevKoln = item_stdevKoln[-len(X_testKoln):]
    item_stdevMN = item_stdevMN[-len(X_testMN):]
    model = trainModel(training_array)
    #model = load_model('my_model.h5')
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,patience=3, min_lr=0.00001)
    #earlyStop=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",verbose=2,mode='min',patience=5)
    history = model.fit(training_array, output_array, epochs=50, batch_size=1,validation_data=(training_val_array,output_val_array),
                        verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    #model.reset_states()
    #history = pickle.load(open('trainHistoryDict','rb'))
    df_history = df_history.append({"Item No_":str(items[index]),
                                    "loss":history.history['loss'],
                                    "val_loss":history.history['val_loss']},ignore_index=True)
    #scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    #scaled_testItem = scaler.fit_transform(lstm_item[lstm_item.columns].values)
    # make a prediction
    try:
         inv_yStgt,inv_yhatStgt=predictTest(lstm_itemStgt,X_testStgt,y_testStgt,model)
         inv_yKoln,inv_yhatKoln=predictTest(lstm_itemKoln,X_testKoln,y_testKoln,model)
         inv_yMN,inv_yhatMN=predictTest(lstm_itemMN,X_testMN,y_testMN,model)
         #temp_future = forecast_future(item_woDummy,7,model,int(len(lstm_item)*0.12))
         #df_future = df_future.append({"Item No_":str(items[item]),"FutureForecasts":temp_future},ignore_index=True)        
         storeStgt = storePrediction(inv_yStgt ,inv_yhatStgt ,item_stdevStgt )
         storeKoln = storePrediction(inv_yKoln,inv_yhatKoln,item_stdevKoln)
         storeMN = storePrediction(inv_yMN,inv_yhatMN,item_stdevMN)
         
         dfForecastsKoln=createDFPredictions(items[index],storeKoln,df_itemDescriptions)
         dfForecastsStgt=createDFPredictions(items[index],storeStgt,df_itemDescriptions)
         dfForecastsMN=createDFPredictions(items[index],storeMN,df_itemDescriptions)
         
         dfAccuracyStgt = accuracyFrame(items[index],inv_yStgt,inv_yhatStgt)
         dfAccuracyKoln = accuracyFrame(items[index],inv_yKoln,inv_yhatKoln)
         dfAccuracyMN = accuracyFrame(items[index],inv_yMN,inv_yhatMN)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: What's the model? It's not possible to make suggestions for improvement without information about the model.

Comment: [Canonical duplicate for “Why do predictions vary less than observations?”](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352)

Comment: My advice, try a different forecasting path here. I believe your data points are perhaps showing large differences due to possible large real variations in the communities where the stores are located. Your chosen forecasting software is perhaps viewing these only apparently aberrant stores as non-repeating or forecastable background noise and is auto modelling to a mean, a good general (but apparently not always) strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. By saying different forecasting path, you mean change your forecast model ? I have tried with SARIMAX models and the prediction results were close to these results actually.

Comment: The question appears to be are the outlier stores continuing to show very poor (more competition) or great (competition has closed) results which could perhaps be modeled by adding a -1,0,+1 dummy variable for respectively a failing store, no change in dynamics, or continuing short term great results.  This dummy should be included only upon confirming the apparent reason for the change in dynamics in select locations.

Comment: The dropout values seem large. What happens if you don't use dropout, or reduce the probability that a unit is dropped?

Comment: @AJKOER Do you mean there is a reason behind these peak values and I should specify that, right? A value over a threshold would be 1 and a value under another threshold would be -1, do you mean a solution like this? But what would be the threshold, mean etc.?

Comment: @Sycorax Same results with more errors, still can't capture the peaks. The forecasts are always periodic but with small variances.

Comment: My idea is to confirm the need for a dummy variable (are there major market disruptions occurring?) and use it to accentuate peaks and valleys predictions as they very well could repeat.

Comment: @AJKOER I see. I do not have any spesific dummy variable except day of week, had a plan to add holidays but not sure that would help. Anyway, I guess you are right, first I should confirm the need for dummy . Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your data seem to have a strong cycle - probably weekly. I would suggest separating this out:

- calculate the 7-day sliding average, and try to predict that
- calculate the weekly variation, and if there is trend in the variation, predict that

Comment: Yes, it is weekly but isnt it better to see the strong cycle, why I should separate and eliminate it ? I tried to predict 7 day sliding average with SARIMAX model, but it was not good enough to be used as forecasting. For your secondsuggestion, I will try that, thanks for the advice.

Comment: "why I should separate and eliminate it ?" So you can identify whether there are other trends that are worth modelling. Then add the weekly cycle back in to your predictions at the end.